# Problem With File Type in Windows Firewall

Tags: windows, firewall, windows-firewall

Hope you are well.
I have some different file type like .txt or .rar that I want to add as a rule in firewall.
I installed a third party app called malwarebytes windows firewall control but still it just let me to add .exe or .dll or .bin or .setup or .scr or .tmp in the rulls.

Is there anyone know how can I do that with windows firewall itself or this application?

Thank you in advance for any help

Comment: You can't block file types in a Firewall, that's not how a firewall works.